# Constant class members are always `undefined`

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the Constants class defined in an Angular project like this:

```
export class Constants
{
    public static CLEANER_STR= 'Cleaner';
    public static dateTimeFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm';
    public static dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd';
};
```

Referring to any constant in any of my components is always `undefined`.
I import the Constant class to my components so there are no compilation errors.
What am I doing wrong?

I refer to the contants in a function:

```
createSchedule(dateStr: string, functionStr: string): Schedule {
    var formDate = new Date(this.form.controls[dateStr].value);
    formDate.setSeconds(0); // Re-set seconds to zero
    
    var date = moment(formDate, Constants.dateTimeFormat).toDate()
    ---> var dateTimeFormat = Constants.dateTimeFormat;
    var formStr1 = this.datePipe.transform(formDate, Constants.dateTimeFormat);
    var formTimeStr = moment(formDate, Constants.dateTimeFormat).toString(); //formDate.getTime();

    var formFunction = this.form.controls[functionStr].value;

    for (let index = 0; index < this.schedules.length; index++) {
      var scheduleTime = new Date(this.schedules[index].date).getTime();//TimeHandler.convertServerDate2Local(this.schedules[index].date).getTime();
      var scheduleTimeStr = this.schedules[index].date;

      var scheduleFunction = this.schedules[index].userFunction;
      if (scheduleTimeStr == formTimeStr && scheduleFunction == formFunction) {
        this.alertService.warn("The user is already " + scheduleFunction + " for that date/time");
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code on how you referring your constants in the component?

Comment: The problem is `:` for both `dateTimeFormat` and `dateFormat`. You shouldn't use this colon syntax as it is for defining the type. You should use `=` to assign value. More like a typo error.

Comment: I added the code where I reference constant `Constants.dateTimeFormat` for example.

Comment: That solved the problem